# Install timescaledb-toolkit in alpine linux

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile, alpine-linux, timescaledb

I have a docker image that is generated using
https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb

The base OS of my docker image is Alpine.
Could not find any document that uses apk to install the toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below part in my dockerfile to install timescaledb-toolkit

> ENV DNF_INSTALL_FLAGS="-y --disableplugin=subscription-manager
> --setopt=tsflags=nodocs --setopt=install_weak_deps=0 --nodocs"
>
> RUN set -ex 
> && microdnf install $DNF_INSTALL_FLAGS 
> openssl 
> wget 
> glibc \   && RUNTIME_INSTALLED_PACKAGES="$(rpm -qa | sort)" 
> && mkdir -p /build/ 
> # Only for build time
> && microdnf install $DNF_INSTALL_FLAGS \
> openssl-devel 
> gcc 
> krb5-devel 
> glibc-devel 
> make 
> cmake 
> tar 
> bzip2 
> git \         curl pkgconfig clang 
> \     && curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y \        && source $HOME/.cargo/env \    && cargo install
> --version '=0.9.7' --force cargo-pgrx \       && cargo pgrx init --pg15 pg_config \   && git clone
> https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit
> /build/timescaledb-toolkit \  && cd
> /build/timescaledb-toolkit/extension \        && cargo pgrx install
> --release \   && cargo run --manifest-path ../tools/post-install/Cargo.toml -- pg_config 
> # Build current version 
> && git clone https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb /build/timescaledb 
> && cd /build/timescaledb && rm -fr build 
> && git checkout ${TS_VERSION} 
> && ./bootstrap -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DREGRESS_CHECKS=OFF -DTAP_CHECKS=OFF -DGENERATE_DOWNGRADE_SCRIPT=ON -DWARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=OFF -DPROJECT_INSTALL_METHOD="docker" 
> && cd build && make install 
> && cd ~ 
>
> # Remove compilation related dependencies.    && echo "Removing all build dependencies." \    && BUILD_DEPENDENCIES=$( comm -13 <( echo
> "$RUNTIME_INSTALLED_PACKAGES" ) <( echo "$(rpm -qa | sort)" ) ) \     &&
> rpm -e --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers
> $BUILD_DEPENDENCIES 
> && microdnf clean all --enablerepo='*' --disableplugin=subscription-manager \     && rustup self uninstall -y \       && rm -rf /root/.cargo \    && rm -rf /root/.rustup \   && rm -rf
> /root/.pgrx 
>
> && rm -rf 
>
> /build 
>
> "${HOME}/.cache" 
>
> /var/cache/yum \
>
> && sed -r -i "s/[#]*\s*(shared_preload_libraries)\s*=\s*'(.*)'/\1 = 'timescaledb,\2'/;s/,'/'/" $(pg_config --sharedir)/postgresql.conf.sample

Answer (score 1):

the [timescaledb-ha](https://hub.docker.com/r/timescale/timescaledb-ha/) contains the timescaledb-toolkit too.

You can see how to implement it [here](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker-ha/blob/master/Dockerfile#L222) if you need to build a custom image.

Comment: That docker file is based on Ubuntu linux and base is timescale-ha. For me its Alpine base and timescale image. I don't have authority to upgrade existing image

Comment: Is there any possibility of including this toolkit in the timescaledb image without ha?